# Wireguard VPN Splitting

Tags: vpn, wireguard, split-tunneling

This is my first time posting here i hope someone can help me. We have staff that is work from home and have **Softphone** installed on their computers. I would like to know if its possible to **tunnel split* of my softphone phone (3cx) to my VPN but if they they to browse from website its not going to be via VPN. Im using WireGuard

Story

Majority of out staff are working remotely
Our FreePBX is cloud based the only way to connect to it  is via VPN which is whitelisted

It came on my idea of VPN Splitting because I cannot use all Traffic to get to the VPN just only the softphone in order to save bandwith

Answer (score 1):

In your `/etc/wireguard/wg0.conf` `[Peer]` section, change the `AllowedIPs` from `0.0.0.0/0` to the local network(s) you want to be accessible via the VPN.